# Gunicorn Fargate ELB healthcecks fail before auto scale

Tags: django, amazon-ecs, gunicorn, amazon-elb

I have setup a django application using gunicorn server on ECS with Fargate backend. I have setup auto scaling based on both CPU and Memory utilisation.

Fargate capacity: 2 vCPU and 4 GB RAM

The problem is that whenever the load is high(number of requests), even before the CPU utilisation is high, the ELB healthchecks are failing and as a result the task is getting deregistered and never leads to auto scaling.

gunicorn is running with 2 workers and 4 threads.

```
gunicorn <appname>.wsgi:application --workers 2 --threads 4
```

I'm trying to understand the reason for this and how to solve this issue.

Comment: What does the memory usage look like when it becomes unresponsive?

Comment: It was pretty low @MarkB. Highest was 22%

Comment: Well you said "whenever the load is high" but you haven't defined what high load is. If CPU and RAM are not high yet, then what is high, the number of requests? Perhaps you should change  your auto scaling to be based on request count if that is the case.

Comment: Yes, It's the number of requests. My question is why is the gunicorn not able to occupy the entire cpu/mem available. It can process more requests if it can use that right? I tried increasing the workers and threads to more than recommended number as well but still no impact!